# Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect error in production when using Bitly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bit.ly

I am using bitly url in my application in 2 cases. In one case I am using it through jQuery as:

```
  function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func)
{
    $.getJSON(
        "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": long_url
        },
        function(response)
        {
            func(response.data.url);
        }
    );
}
```

and in other case I am using bitly gem with version 1.0.2. For this I am adding

view:

```
<%= f.input :link_placeholder, :as => :text, :label => false, :input_html => { :id => 'copy_link', :class => '', :value => "#{get_bitly_url(user_report_url(@user, @report))}", :rows => 2, :cols => 30, :maxlength => 490} %>
```

controller:

```
  def show
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    @bitly_url = get_bitly_url("#{user_reports_url}/#{@report.id}")    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @report }
    end
  end
  def get_bitly_url(url)
    if Rails.env.development?
      return url
    else
      bitly = Bitly.new('myapp', 'R_e2pd1dca0442a20a2qwqw59156e3260d')
      bitly.shorten(url).short_url
    end
  end
```

the above 2 are working fine in development mode and rails production mode and I also tried in AWS EC2 instance with Apache and Phusion, it is working great
  but it is not working in the main production server where the domain name is mentioned in the url with "https".

These are the errors I am getting:

> Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect):
>   app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:342:in `get_bitly_url'
>
>   app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:35:in`show'

The url mentioned in show is coming from js file as mentioned above.

Please help me to get out of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says **peer - SSL_connect**, this may be networking issue. So, check whether the bitly port is open from your network or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also replaced bitly url as `https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?`

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when server is broken. Did you check if the url's are right on the main server? If it works on dev, should work on production as well. Good luck!